# Wordpress breaking out of the template

Tags: css, wordpress, templates, html

How do I go about making the below slider @ http://360builders.com.au/360-homes/custom-designs/ the full width of the page 1140px wide?

Currently I am stuck due to the right hand sidebar widget. Is there a way I can style a DIV that breaks out from the content area, in which I can then place the slider?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the `<div id="SlideDeck-571-frame"> after <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar widget-area">` as @Cem suggested, but you should do it in a new template file, and then set that page's template to this new template. Saying that, you should better do another thing: create a child theme, and put the new template and maybe your customized style.css as well under the child theme folder, so that when you upgrade wordpress, your customized part is not lost.

I've said a few things. To reiterate,

1. Create a child theme, and active the child theme.
   There are a lot of guide posts about this. Maybe this is an official one you can have a look: [how to create a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).
2. Create a new template file. The crucial part is the header lines:

   ```
   <?php
   /*
   Template Name: splash-page
   */
   ?>
   ```

   You can copy the other part from the default template and make whatever changes you want.
3. Save the new template file in the child theme folder ( for example,  wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child). You will customize the style.css file as well. Put your customzed style.css file under the child theme folder as well.
4. Now go to the WordPress admin, View all pages, edit that page. You should see the new template listed in template drop down menu. Apply it.
5. After this works, in the future all changes to the new template and style.css can be uploaded using ftp, which should be faster.

   Hope it helps.

Comment: I was thinking this would be the only way, thanks for your help! Learning curve here I come... I know the theme already works off a child theme so it shouldnt be too hard. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try to place the `<div id="SlideDeck-571-frame">` after `<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar widget-area">` then you can set the width size to maximum size of page.

Comment: This works, however I'm using WordPress and this is the "default-template" so I cant throw the DIV after the sidebar as it would then appear on every page using this template.

I was hoping I could style a DIV within the content area of this page in WordPress. Allowing it to break out of the <div class="post-10 page type-page status-publish hentry entry"> its bound by...

Hope this make sense...

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning a DIV worked (http://360builders.com.au/360-homes/test/), but not with the responsiveness of the theme...

```
#box {
    width: 1100px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 680px;
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    /* ADD THE OVERFLOW */
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
}

#container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

#x {
    width: 1100px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #fff;
}
```